# How to retrieve data from Excel using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I like to retrieve the data from excel sheet using linq, I saw ExcelqueryFactory for that in some sites. I don't know the namespace or reference for that. I am using .net3.5 framework(visual studio2008). Is it possible to use it in .net3.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use LINQ against Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059807/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-against-excel)

Answer (score 7):

I think ExcelQueryFactory come from .net framework 4.0 . We need to inculde dll for access that class in .net3.5.From below link we can get that.

http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/source/browse/trunk/src/LinqToExcel/ExcelQueryFactory.cs?r=50

Below example code show how we retrieve from Excel using ExcelQueryFactory

```
var book = new ExcelQueryFactory("pathToExcelFile");
var australia = from x in book.Worksheet()
                where x["Country"] == "Aust"
                select new
                {
                   Country = x["Country"],
                   BookCode = x["Code"],
                   BookName = x["Name"]
                };
```

Comment: The link goes to empty page (22 oct 2018)

Answer (score -2):

Try to obtain data to DataTable or any other collection using OleDb and process collection by LINQ. I can post or send obtaining sources bit later.